# Андроид студия студия выдает ошибку: Класс не является абстрактным и не реализует абстрактный член public abstract fun onCameraPosition

Tags: yandexmapkit

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему при компиляции проекта андроид студия выдает ошибку

> :Класс 'Karta' не является абстрактным и не реализует абстрактный член public abstract fun onCameraPositionChanged(p0: Map, p1: CameraPosition, p2: CameraUpdateSource, p3: Boolean): Единица измерения, определенная в com.yandex.mapkit.map.CameraListener

Код:

```
class Karta : AppCompatActivity(), Session.SearchListener,UserLocationObjectListener,
    CameraListener {
    /**
     * Replace "your_api_key" with a valid developer key.
     * You can get it at the https://developer.tech.yandex.ru/ website.
     */
    private lateinit var userLocationLayer: UserLocationLayer

    private var routeStartLocation = Point(0.0, 0.0)

    private var permissionLocation = false
    private var followUserLocation = false

    private val MAPKIT_API_KEY = "98d6ff88-e2bc-4e2b-a9a3-ec2e87b332aa"
    private var mapView: MapView? = null
    private var searchEdit: EditText? = null
    private var searchManager: SearchManager? = null
    private var searchSession: Session? = null
    private fun submitQuery(query: String) {
        searchSession = searchManager!!.submit(
            query,
            VisibleRegionUtils.toPolygon(mapView!!.map.visibleRegion),
            SearchOptions(),
            this
        )
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        MapKitFactory.setApiKey(MAPKIT_API_KEY)
        MapKitFactory.initialize(this)
        SearchFactory.initialize(this)
        setContentView(R.layout.karta)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        checkPermission()

        userInterface()

        searchManager = SearchFactory.getInstance().createSearchManager(SearchManagerType.COMBINED)
        mapView = findViewById<View>(R.id.mapview) as MapView
        mapView!!.map.addCameraListener(this)
        searchEdit = findViewById<View>(R.id.search_edit) as EditText
        searchEdit!!.setOnEditorActionListener { textView, actionId, keyEvent ->
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                submitQuery(searchEdit!!.text.toString())
            }
            false
        }


        var mapKit: MapKit = MapKitFactory.getInstance()
        requestLocationPermission()

        var locationonmapkit = mapKit.createUserLocationLayer(mapview.mapWindow)
        locationonmapkit.isVisible = true

        mapview.map.move(
            CameraPosition(Point(54.345241, 84.209828), 11.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
            Animation(Animation.Type.SMOOTH, 4f), null
        )
        submitQuery(searchEdit!!.text.toString())



    }

    private fun requestLocationPermission() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                arrayOf(
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
                ),
                0
            )
            return

        }
    }

    private fun checkPermission() {
        val permissionLocation =
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
        if (permissionLocation != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
                requestPermissionLocation
            )
        } else {
            onMapReady()
        }
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        when (requestCode) {
            requestPermissionLocation -> {
                if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    onMapReady()
                }

                return
            }
        }
    }

    private fun userInterface() {
        val mapLogoAlignment = Alignment(HorizontalAlignment.LEFT, VerticalAlignment.BOTTOM)
        mapview.map.logo.setAlignment(mapLogoAlignment)

        user_location_fab.setOnClickListener {
            if (permissionLocation) {
                cameraUserPosition()

                followUserLocation = true
            } else {
                checkPermission()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun onMapReady() {
        val mapKit = MapKitFactory.getInstance()
        userLocationLayer = mapKit.createUserLocationLayer(mapview.mapWindow)
        userLocationLayer.isVisible = true
        userLocationLayer.isHeadingEnabled = true
        userLocationLayer.setObjectListener(this)

        mapview.map.addCameraListener(this)

        cameraUserPosition()

        permissionLocation = true
    }

    private fun cameraUserPosition() {
        if (userLocationLayer.cameraPosition() != null) {
            routeStartLocation = userLocationLayer.cameraPosition()!!.target
            mapview.map.move(
                CameraPosition(routeStartLocation, 16f, 0f, 0f), Animation(Animation.Type.SMOOTH, 1f), null
            )
        } else {
            mapview.map.move(CameraPosition(Point(0.0, 0.0), 16f, 0f, 0f))
        }
    }



    private fun setAnchor() {
        userLocationLayer.setAnchor(
            PointF((mapview.width * 0.5).toFloat(), (mapview.height * 0.5).toFloat()),
            PointF((mapview.width * 0.5).toFloat(), (mapview.height * 0.83).toFloat())
        )

        user_location_fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_my_location_black_24dp)

        followUserLocation = false
    }

    private fun noAnchor() {
        userLocationLayer.resetAnchor()

        user_location_fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_location_searching_black_24dp)
    }

    override fun onObjectAdded(userLocationView: UserLocationView) {
        setAnchor()

        userLocationView.pin.setIcon(ImageProvider.fromResource(this, R.drawable.user_arrow))
        userLocationView.arrow.setIcon(ImageProvider.fromResource(this, R.drawable.user_arrow))
        userLocationView.accuracyCircle.fillColor = Color.BLUE
    }

    override fun onObjectUpdated(p0: UserLocationView, p1: ObjectEvent) {}

    override fun onObjectRemoved(p0: UserLocationView) {}

    override fun onStop() {
        mapView!!.onStop()
        MapKitFactory.getInstance().onStop()
        super.onStop()
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        MapKitFactory.getInstance().onStart()
        mapView!!.onStart()
    }

    override fun onSearchResponse(response: Response) {
        val mapObjects = mapView!!.map.mapObjects
        mapObjects.clear()
        for (searchResult in response.collection.children) {
            val resultLocation = searchResult.obj!!.geometry[0].point
            if (resultLocation != null) {
                mapObjects.addPlacemark(
                    resultLocation,
                    ImageProvider.fromResource(this, R.drawable.search_result)
                )
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onSearchError(error: Error) {
        var errorMessage = "Неизвестная ошибка!"
        if (error is RemoteError){
            errorMessage = "Беспроводная ошибка!"
        }else if (error is NetworkError){
            errorMessage = "Проблема с интернетом!"
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    override fun onCameraPositionChanged(
        map: Map,
        cameraPosition: CameraPosition,
        cameraUpdateReason: CameraUpdateReason,
        finish: Boolean
    ) {
        if (finish) {
            submitQuery(searchEdit!!.text.toString())
            if (finish) {
                if (followUserLocation) {
                    setAnchor()
                }
            } else {
                if (!followUserLocation) {
                    noAnchor()
                }
            }
        }
        }
    companion object {
        /**
         * Replace "your_api_key" with a valid developer key.
         * You can get it at the https://developer.tech.yandex.ru/ website.
         */
        const val mapKitApiKey = "98d6ff88-e2bc-4e2b-a9a3-ec2e87b332aa"
        const val requestPermissionLocation = 1
    }
}
```

Xml код:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <com.yandex.mapkit.mapview.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:id="@+id/search_edit"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:hint="  Поиск"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:background="@drawable/poisk"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="61dp"
        android:layout_height="104dp"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/назад"
        android:onClick="imageButton2"
        android:src="@drawable/common_full_open_on_phone"
        tools:ignore="ImageContrastCheck,MissingConstraints,UsingOnClickInXml" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/user_location_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorNull"
        app:elevation="8dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_location_disabled_black_24dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, эта ошибка связана с тем, что в классе `Karta` не реализован абстрактный метод `onCameraPositionChanged()`, который определен в интерфейсе `CameraListener`. Можно попробовать реализовать метод в классе `Karta`

Comment: А как это сделать?